# For loop not going beyond first day in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, for-loop, foreach

I am trying to create a for loop to get the min and max temperature of each day and output it. I am using Open Weather API. I have attached an image of what the data looks like when called. Please feel free to ask any questions. I don't know what types of things to clarify. Here is my javascript.

```
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=43.6121&lon=-116.3915&exclude=hourly,minutely&units=imperial&APPID=98cbc04c44e9fc2905a70710f2643e4e')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((jsObject) => {
    console.log(jsObject);

let temp = jsObject.current.temp;
let minTemp = jsObject.daily[0].temp.min;
let maxTemp = jsObject.daily[0].temp.max;

document.getElementById('condition').textContent = jsObject.current.weather[0].main;
document.getElementById('temp-min').textContent = Math.round(minTemp);
document.getElementById('temp-max').textContent = Math.round(maxTemp);
document.getElementById('temp-current').textContent = Math.round(temp);

    
    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sun";
    weekday[1] = "Mon";
    weekday[2] = "Tue";
    weekday[3] = "Wed";
    weekday[4] = "Thu";
    weekday[5] = "Fri";
    weekday[6] = "Sat";

    var data = jsObject.daily;
    var dayOfWeek = document.getElementsByClassName("forecast-day");
    var weatherIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("weatherIcon");
    var tempMax = document.getElementsByClassName("forecast-max");
    var tempMin = document.getElementsByClassName("forecast-min");

    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var d = new Date(data[i]);
        dayOfWeek[i].textContent = weekday[d.getDay()];

        const imagesrc = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data[i].weather[i].icon + '.png';
        const description = data[i].weather[i].description;
        weatherIcon[i].setAttribute('src', imagesrc);
        weatherIcon[i].setAttribute('alt', description);

        tempMax[i].innerHTML = Math.round(data[i].temp.max) + " &#176;F";
        tempMin[i].innerHTML = Math.round(data[i].temp.min) + " &#176;F";

    }
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/boWF9.png

Comment: You could explain the current behavior of your code and what you expect instead. Also include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working snippet of your code. You weren't accessing the date value correctly `var d = new Date(data[i].dt);` (not `new Date(data[i])`) which was causing the other date-dependent items to fail. Once that was fixed, the day of the week needed adjusting to  `weekday[d.getDay()+i];`. The `data[i].weather[i]` references needed were incorrect (weather had just one index) `data[i].weather[0]`.

To test, I generated the divs and img elements so the format is off, but you can see they all get populated.

```js
/* this section is just to generate the elements for testing */
let a = ['condition', 'temp-min', 'temp-max', 'temp-current'];
a.forEach(b => {
  document.querySelector('#boxes').innerHTML += "<div id='" + b + "'>---" + b + "---</div>";
})
a = ["forecast-day", "forecast-max", "forecast-min"];
a.forEach(b => {
  for (let x = 0; x < 7; x++) document.querySelector('#boxes').innerHTML += "<div class='" + b + "'>---" + b + "---</div>";
})
a = ["weatherIcon"];
a.forEach(b => {
  for (let x = 0; x < 7; x++) document.querySelector('#boxes').innerHTML += "<img class='" + b + "'>";
})

/* Your code */
fetch('https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/onecall?lat=43.6121&lon=-116.3915&exclude=hourly,minutely&units=imperial&APPID=98cbc04c44e9fc2905a70710f2643e4e')
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((jsObject) => {
    let temp = jsObject.current.temp;
    let minTemp = +jsObject.daily[0].temp.min;
    let maxTemp = +jsObject.daily[0].temp.max;

    document.getElementById('condition').textContent = jsObject.current.weather[0].main;
    document.getElementById('temp-min').textContent = Math.round(minTemp);
    document.getElementById('temp-max').textContent = Math.round(maxTemp);
    document.getElementById('temp-current').textContent = Math.round(temp);

    var weekday = new Array(7);
    weekday[0] = "Sun";
    weekday[1] = "Mon";
    weekday[2] = "Tue";
    weekday[3] = "Wed";
    weekday[4] = "Thu";
    weekday[5] = "Fri";
    weekday[6] = "Sat";

    var data = jsObject.daily;
    var dayOfWeek = document.getElementsByClassName("forecast-day");
    var weatherIcon = document.getElementsByClassName("weatherIcon");
    var tempMax = document.getElementsByClassName("forecast-max");
    var tempMin = document.getElementsByClassName("forecast-min");
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      var d = new Date(data[i].dt);
       dayOfWeek[i].textContent = weekday[d.getDay()+i];
      const imagesrc = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + data[i].weather[0].icon + '.png';
      const description = data[i].weather[0].description;
      weatherIcon[i].setAttribute('src', imagesrc);
      weatherIcon[i].setAttribute('alt', description);

      tempMax[i].innerHTML = Math.round(data[i].temp.max) + " &#176;F";
      tempMin[i].innerHTML = Math.round(data[i].temp.min) + " &#176;F";

    }
  })
```

```css
div {
  margin: 2px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div id='boxes'></div>
```

Comment: That is it right there! I thought it was off.... I had used this previously but with a slightly different call reference. Thank you kindly!

Comment: The only issue is that it's outputting Monday on all of them....

Comment: got it - updated with `weekday[d.getDay()+i];`

Answer (score 1):

According to what I see in that server's response, `weather` property of each element of `daily` array has just one element. Yet your code is trying to access more than that with `data[i].weather[i].icon` expression, starting from the second iteration of the loop (when `i` is 1).

The code blows then, as `data[i].weather[i]` is undefined, and you're trying to work with that as with an object (accessing its `icon` property). As all of that is executed inside `then`, either you should see `Unhandled promise rejection`... in your console or (and that's really bad) it just fails silently because of some forgiving `catch` handler.

Solution seems to be rather simple: replace all `data[i].weather[i]` with `data[i].weather[0]` parts. Or (much better) just store this in some temp variable, like this:

```
const weather = data[i].weather[0];

const imagesrc = 'https://openweathermap.org/img/w/' + weather.icon + '.png';
weatherIcon[i].setAttribute('src', imagesrc);
weatherIcon[i].setAttribute('alt', weather.description);
```

As a sidenote, I'd suggest refactoring your code so that it iterates over the collected DOM elements, and not the server's response. There's a chance for mismatch, as there's 8 elements (days) there, but it's hard to say how many `.forecast-day`, `.forecast-max`, etc... elements are in your DOM.

Comment: Mmmm that is a fair point. Thanks for the info.